# Error in x[ind, ] - centerI : non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, clustered-index

I have a time series data set. I would like to cluster it using different clustering techniques. Then, I would like to evaluate each method. I tried an R code from `clusterSim` package. However, I got an error"

`Error in x[ind, ] - centerI : non-conformable arrays`. I have no idea why I got this error.

Here is my code:

```
library(dtwclust)
library(Tsclust)
library(dplyr)
library(clusterSim)
data("interest.rates")
rate.change <- diff(log(interest.rates), 1)
md <- diss(rate.change, "AR.MAH")$p_value
min_nc=2
max_nc=8
res <- array(0, c(max_nc-min_nc+1, 2))
res[,1] <- min_nc:max_nc
clusters <- NULL
for (nc in min_nc:max_nc)
{
  hc <- hclust(md, method="average")
  cl2 <- cutree(hc, k=nc)
  res[nc-min_nc+1, 2] <- DB <- index.DB(rate.change, cl2, md,centrotypes="medoids")$DB
  clusters <- rbind(clusters, cl2)
}rate.change <- diff(log(interest.rates),1)
```

**The original code is as follows:**

```
# Example 3
library(clusterSim)
data(data_ratio)
md <- dist(data_ratio, method="euclidean")
# nc - number_of_clusters
min_nc=2
max_nc=8
res <- array(0, c(max_nc-min_nc+1, 2))
res[,1] <- min_nc:max_nc
clusters <- NULL
for (nc in min_nc:max_nc)
{
hc <- hclust(md, method="complete")
cl2 <- cutree(hc, k=nc)
res[nc-min_nc+1, 2] <- DB <- index.DB(data_ratio, cl2, centrotypes="centroids")$DB
clusters <- rbind(clusters, cl2)
}
```

Comment: Hi Maryam. I'm afraid we have no idea either since we don't have the data set you used. We don't know what `rate.change` is, nor which package has `data("interest.rates")`included, nor is this easily discoverable by Googling. There is no way to debug your code without this information, and therefore no way to answer the question in its current format. I'm afraid I'm going to have to close it for that reason, but would be happy to revert this if you edit the question to make it answerable in principle.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you so much for your comment. I am so sorry, I forgot to add the package and the data. It is really an accident. I will edit the question.

Comment: thanks. I have voted to reopen and will have a look meantime